# How to get a list of values from tuples which the second value is the same as first in the next tuple?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm having trouble trying to create a list of values from a list of tuples, which link to where the second value is the same as the first value in another tuple, that starts and ends with certain values.

For example:

```
start = 11
end = 0

list_tups = [(0,1),(0, 2),(0, 3),(261, 0),(8, 15),(118, 32),(11, 8),(15, 118),(32, 261)]
```

So I want to iterate through those list of tups, starting with the one which is the same as the start value and searching through the tups where it'll end with the end value.

So my desired output would be:

```
[11, 8, 15, 118, 32, 261, 0]
```

I understand how to check the values i'm just having trouble with interating through the tuples every time to check if there is a tuple in the list that matches the second value.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing pathfinding in a directed graph.

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> g = nx.DiGraph(list_tups)
>>> nx.shortest_path(g, start, end)
[11, 8, 15, 118, 32, 261, 0]
```

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't work with `end = 0` because there is no 0 at the end, but here it is with 32:

```
>>> start = 11
>>> end = 32
>>> flattened = [i for t in list_tups for i in t]
>>> flattened[flattened.index(start):flattened.index(end, flattened.index(start))+1]
[11, 8, 15, 118, 32]
```

Comment: `(261, 0)` is the edge with end at 0.

Answer (score -1):

You can recursively search the tuples, moving the start value closer and closer. The path will be accumulated as we move back up through the chain You may need to tweak the path a little to get your desired outcome (I believe you'll need to append the first starting value, then reverse it).

```py
def find(start, end, tuples, path):
    for t in tuples:
        if t[0] == start:
            if t[1] == end or find(t[1], end, tuples):
                path.append(t[1])
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: This is O(n^2), very inefficient approach.  It may also exceed Python's recursion limit for larger graphs.